# PhD scholarship in nanoporous material; how to advertise?

Tags: phd, funding, recruiting

I would like to advertise some PhD scholarship positions located a Sydney, Australia in the fabrication of novel nanoporous material like mesoporous silica. I am finding that it is not straightforward to advertise locally and internally. Most of the big scholarship and general job  sites are expensive to post too.

What other options exist for finding candidates?

Comment: Are you trying to recruit international applicants? I.e., is this question more about where in the world to find students interested in your discipline? or about how to advertise to students in Australia?

Comment: I'm in a different field but I often see these advertised through relevant societies (through their email list and often also on their website)

Comment: thank you very much for your comments. relevant societies is a good idea. i am hoping to attract local Australian and overseas students. the best response we have had so far is from the free websites http://scholarship-positions.com and the free chinese website emuch.net/bbs/ but you have to get help from somebody who speaks Mandarin to set it up. tom

Answer (score 1):

Are there discussion boards, social media accounts, or email lists for societies or interest groups that are directly/indirectly part of your field? Can you email the links to other researchers (the ones you cite or who cite you)? Perhaps there are researchers who are particularly adept at their internet presence (websites, social media accounts etc) who would be willing to share the information.

In my field, there are numerous opportunities for free advertising on all of the above-mentioned areas. Most faculty I know of are happy to share opportunities like that for students, since they recognize funded opportunities are increasingly rare.

Answer (score 0):

Posting to social media is free, but only useful if you make the effort to identify and connect with people that might be connected to good candidates. Likewise, you could post to professional and academic mailing lists related to nanotechnology.  Finally, you could send direct emails to the Department Chairs for relevant departments in Australia (Materials, Chemical Engineering, Chemistry, Industrial Engineering, or what ever fits).

Answer (score 0):

Sponsor your post in facebook & show this advertisement only to those who have interest about that particular topic.